# WPF Observablecollection with INotifyPropertyChanged for ListView doesn't work

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a wpf application and I want to update my listview when I add new value through the UI using Observablecollect. But I don't get what I expect. When I add new value I won't update my list view.

Here is my CS file.

```
 using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Windows;

 namespace ObservableCollectionTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<TestUser> NameList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NameList = GetNamesFromDBAsStringList();
        ListViewNames.ItemsSource = NameList;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestUser user = new TestUser();
        user.UserName = txtName.Text;
        NameList.Add(user);

        //InsertUserName(txtName.Text);
        //NameList = GetNamesFromDBAsStringList();

        txtName.Clear();
        MessageBox.Show("User added");
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TestUser> GetNamesFromDBAsStringList()
    {
        ObservableCollection<TestUser> userList = new ObservableCollection<TestUser>();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Chakrapani\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "select UserID,UserName from TestUser";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            TestUser testUser = new TestUser();
            testUser.UserID = (int)reader[0];
            testUser.UserName = reader[1].ToString();
            userList.Add(testUser);
        }
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();

        return userList;
    }

    private void InsertUserName(string userName)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=CHAKRAPANI\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
        connection.Open();
        string sql = string.Format("insert into TestUser values ('{0}')", userName);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
}

public class TestUser : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _userId;
    private string _userName;

    public int UserID
    {
        get { return _userId; }
        set
        {
            _userId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("UserID");
        }
    }
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _userName; }
        set
        {
            _userName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("UserName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
}
```

And this is my xaml file

```
<Window x:Class="ObservableCollectionTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="396">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Add User" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1" Name="BtnAdd"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" Name="txtName"/>
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="259" Margin="10,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" Name="ListViewNames" ItemsSource="{Binding MyUserNameList}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="User ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserID}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="User Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Please give me a clue to handle the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add the DataContext in your constructor :

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: thanks, I did according to your suggestion. But I can't send my added data to database.

Answer (score 1):

You should insert it into observable collection instead of re-building it

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TestUser user = new TestUser();
    user.UserName = txtName.Text;
    InsertUserName(txtName.Text);
    NameList.Add(new TestUser {UserName = txtName.Text, UserID = ???}); //TODO: assign correct ID
    txtName.Clear();
    MessageBox.Show("User added");
}
```

Comment: I did according to your suggestion and updated my question. Now my List view get updated. but added values do not go to database. How to send my newly added data to database?

Comment: You should store into db, before adding to the list, observable collection doesn't save anything to db

Comment: Thank you very much ArsenMkrt. That's the thing that I wanted to know.

Comment: There is another question I got, then what is the usage of INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Without it also, my purpose works now.

Comment: Yes, ObervableCollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged interface which is enough for updating add/remove item.On the other hand whey you update UserName like this: NameList[0].UserName = "new user name"; this will update the view only if you have INotifyPropertyChanged